# Объекты компонента TImage

Tags: c++, c++builder, embarcadero

Мне нужно создать двусвязный список из нарисованных мною картинок. Рисую я в компоненте TImage (прямоугольники и эллипсы). У меня есть метод добавления элемента в список, который имеет универсальный тип параметров. Подскажите, объект какого класса мне передавать в качестве параметра, т.е. чтобы параметром была именно моя картинка( TImage, TPicture и т.д.). Пример:

```
Image1->Canvas->Pen->Color=clOlive;
Image1->Canvas->Brush->Color=clMoneyGreen;
Image1->Canvas->Ellipse(x1,y1,x1+diameter,y1+diameter);
figure->enqueue(/*тип моего изображения*/);
```

Comment: Какой смысл Вы вкладываете в слово "двусвязный"? Ответ на Ваш вопрос: `TBitmap`.

Comment: Создать нужно двусвязный список типа очередь. А как мне передавать в функцию мой рисунок из компонента TImage, не подскажете?

Comment: "Создать нужно двусвязный список типа очередь" - слова вроде все понятные, а вместе - никак.

Comment: Я не понимаю, что вызывает затруднения в понимании вопроса

Comment: Затруднение - в соединении понятий "двусвязность" и "очередь". Какой смысл Вы вкладываете в слово "двусвязный"?

Comment: в списке каждый элемент будет иметь указатель на предыдущий и следующий (двусвязность), добавляем в список только с конца, а удаляем только из начала (очередь)

Comment: очередь  может хранить два указателья, чтоб добавить в конец и вытащить с начала, но это не двусвязность. И для чего двусвязность там, когда вставляешь только  в один конец и выводишь с обратного конца?...

Comment: Вы не понимаете концепций списков. Очередь реализовывается в виде списка